# How can I run the mssql functions in php?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, apache, sql-server-2005

I'm getting this annoying message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()

I've read many threads where they say just uncomment the `php_mssql.dll`, but there is no such file in my extension folder and neither is it listed in `php.ini`.

And I can't seem to find it anywhere. All the links posted on forums are broken, and I'm completely broken by this.

I also tried to download recent files from Microsoft, I unpacked this one: `php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll`, and have added it in the extensions list but I still get the same error.

Is there any meaningful way one can do this? Or maybe I need to reinstall PHP?

**EDIT**

I added the following files to the `php.ini` extensions:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
```

But still no luck... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, this is how I solved it:

I simply installed php 5.2, then added native mssql extensions, I think it looked like:

```
extension=php_mssql.dll
```

Unlike 5.3, the 5.2 version has the native binaries that work with mssql for Windows.

(Installing PDO is not an option for many people, as it requires too much work and also learning some new syntax, even though it's supposed to be more 'reliable').

Finally, I downloaded msvcr71.dll from

```
http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?msvcr71
```

Without this file the connection to server is being cut and and is unstable.

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my way of linking php 5.3 with sql-server 2008 together on windows platform (using PDO instead of mssql_* functions):

First of all, you need to install [microsoft mssql native client](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978) (scroll the page down to "Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Native Client"); after doing that, leave only extension in php.ini:

`extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll`

now, check the extension list by calling `php -m` from cmd:
You should see `pdo_mssql` in [PHP Modules] section;

Now, restart the apache. You can connect to the server by calling new PDO():

`$connection = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost,1521;Database=testdb", "UserName", "Password");`

More information can be found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php)